# Manipulating lines in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've created a line in Corona using display.newLine() thanks to tutorials online. I'm still learning, so I have a few questions.

Is it possible to create touch events for the drawn line? Like once I have the line on my scene, if I touch that line, something should happen.

If it is possible, how do I do this? I tried what I would do with other objects and used something like line:addEventListener("touch", something) but it did not work.

Also, is it possible to create some sort of animation for the drawn line? Like draw the line, the after a few frames, erase it and draw a new one? (I'm talking about automatically instead of drawing it through touch events)

Lastly, is it possible to draw a curved line using only 1 line? I'm trying to avoid having to use so many lines if I'm going to create some sort of animation using the line drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create touch events for the drawn line?

Yes, according to [Corona Labs API for `LineObject`s](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/LineObject/index.html#methods), the methods and properties are inherited from [`DisplayObject`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/index.html#methods) and one of those methods include [`EventListener`s](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/EventListener/addEventListener.html). You can try it like this:

```
local line = display.newLine( ... )
line:addEventListener( "tap", myFunc )
```

> Is it possible to create some sort of animation for the drawn line?
>   Like draw the line, the after a few frames, erase it and draw a new
>   one?

Once again, yes. You can use the [`performWithDelay`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html) method from the `timer` table. An example would be like this:

```
i, line = 30, display.newLine( 20, 50, 200, 300 )
changeText = function()
  line.x1 = 20 + (i % 80)
  line.x2 = 50 + (i % 100)
  i = i * 2
end
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, changeText )
```

> Is it possible to draw a curved line using only 1 line?

You need to read a bit about geometry. A line can not be curved. Otherwise a circle wouldn't be a polygon.

Comment: This does not work (at least not any more). The official documentation here http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newLine.html says "Currently, display.newLine() objects do not support touch/tap events.", and I have been unable to move the line by changing x1 or y1.